# IP Camera Python 3 Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, python-3.x, ip-camera

I am working on using Python 3 to take an IP web camera's stream and display it on my computer. The following code only works in python 2.7

```
import cv2
import urllib 
import numpy as np

stream=urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.0.90/mjpg/video.mjpg')
bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(16384)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('i',i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

However when I try it on Python 3 I get the following error

> stream=urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.0.90/mjpg/video.mjpg')
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Is there any fix for this? I tried making my own buffer but there isn't much information out there on this stuff

Comment: maybe you could give this a try next time https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html it automatically translates py2 to py3, seems to cover urllib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python3 you need `import urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request

stream = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.0.90/mjpg/video.mjpg')
```